# Create e-book standalone app in the iOS App Store - Free with external access code

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I'm a long time iOS developer and i've been out of the domain for a while now,
I've been assigned a new task in which i need to check whether it's doable on the appStore or not. 
My aim is to create an e-book like application, where the user downloads the app for free from the appStore, and is requested to enter an access code provided separately outside the appStore.
So the app can be free on the store, and once opened an external ajax/php request will take place to authenticate the user. 
Previously, apple forbid this kind of transaction, i am checking now to see if this situation changed or/and is now approved by apple.
Many Thanks!

Comment: No - see [3.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase)

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you, can you please post it as an answer so i'd accept it?